# Processing pairs of values from two sequences in Clojure

Tags: python, clojure, zip

I'm trying to get into the Clojure community. I've been working a lot with Python, and one of the features I make extensive use of is the zip() method, for iterating over pairs of values. Is there a (clever and short) way of achieving the same in Clojure?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Another way is to simply use map together with some function that collects its arguments in a sequence, like this:

```
user=> (map vector '(1 2 3) "abc")
([1 \a] [2 \b] [3 \c])
```

Answer (score 4):

```
(zipmap [:a :b :c] (range 3))
-> {:c 2, :b 1, :a 0}
```

Iterating over maps happens pairwise, e.g. like this:

```
(doseq [[k v] (zipmap [:a :b :c] (range 3))]
  (printf "key: %s, value: %s\n" k v))
```

prints:

```
key: :c, value: 2
key: :b, value: 1
key: :a, value: 0
```

Comment: I tested the approach, and it couldn't handle three or more sequences. I should have mentioned that requirement in the initial question, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

The question has been answered, but there's still `interleave`, which also handles an arbitrary number of sequences, but does not group the resulting sequence into tuples (but you can use `partition` for that).